# Is the anticanonical bundle of a compact Kähler manifold positive?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am working on the proof of the Kodaira embedding theorem and on one part of this proof you have "$−K_{X}+L^{\otimes k}$ is positive". Since it is part of the requirements, it is clear that $L$ is positive. But generally, is the following statement true?

> Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Then the anticanonical bundle $−K_{X}$ (or $K_{X}^{*}$) is positive.

Comment: It is a good exercise to calculate the canonical bundle of all smooth curves in $\mathbf P^2$, all smooth surfaces in $\mathbf P^3$, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A holomorphic line bundle $L$ on a compact complex manifold $X$ is positive if $c_1(L) \in H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$ can be represented by a closed positive $(1, 1)$-form. It follows that $X$ admits a Kähler metric with Kähler form $\omega$ such that $c_1(L) = [\omega]$. In particular, if your claim were true, a compact complex manifold would be Kähler if and only if had positive anticanonical bundle - as we will see, this is far from true.

On a compact Riemann surface $X$, a holomorphic line bundle $L$ has a degree: if $c_1(L) = [\alpha]$, then

$$\deg L = \langle c_1(L), [X]\rangle = \int_X\alpha.$$

In particular, if $L$ is positive, $c_1(L) = [\omega]$ so

$$\deg L = \int_X\omega > 0.$$

On a Riemann surface, $K_X^* = TX$ so

$$\deg K_X^* = \deg TX = \langle c_1(TX), [X]\rangle = \langle e(TX), [X]\rangle = \chi(X)$$

where $e(TX)$ denotes the Euler class of $TX$. We see that if $X$ is a compact Riemann surface with positive anticanonical bundle,

$$\chi(X) > 0.$$

As $\chi(X) = 2 - 2g$ where $g$ is the genus of $X$, the only compact Riemann surface with positive anticanonical bundle is $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

A compact complex manifold with positive anticanonical bundle is called *Fano*. By the Kodaira embedding theorem, such a manifold is projective, so any compact Kähler, non-projective manifold will also provide a counterexample to your claim. Furthermore, if $K_X^*$ is positive, $K_X$ is negative so $X$ has Kodaira dimension $-\infty$. This provides another class of counterexamples: Kähler manifolds with non-negative Kodaira dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement Michael Albanese's nice answer:  one should think of positive anticanonical bundle as being unusual.  [*General type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_dimension#General_type) varieties have maximal (in particular, positive) Kodaira dimension, and so it is their canonical bundles that tend to be positive, rather than their anticanonical bundles.  (Literally, a variety is general type if its canonical bundle is [big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iitaka_dimension#Big_line_bundles), which is weaker than being positive/ample, but is an assumption in a similar direction.  Thanks to Michael Albanese for correcting an earlier incorrect statement here.)

As the name suggests, you should imagine that a typical, or general, variety, is of general type.

Comment: While positive canonical bundle implies general type, the converse is not true.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Thanks for the correction; I got myself confused.